# Do #defines in HLSL add any performance overhead?

Tags: hlsl, shader

In HLSL is the preprocessor equivalent to the one in C(++) where it literally alters the code before compilation? If this is the case then using such methods would seem to allow specializing a shader without adding run-time conditional statements... is that true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`#define`s work as you expect them to. They are evaluated at compile-time.

If you would like to check the output of the compiler to be sure that there is no (unnecessary) branching occurring, use the `/Fc <file>` option to the HLSL compiler (fxc) to generate an assembly listing of the compiled shader.